# Change list item color inside radio button list in Asp net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using a radio RadioButtonList in asp net to create 2 radio button that when selected are supposed to change color the first one being green and the second one red but i am not able to make the change said color
Tldr:Change to list item1 little circle inside list item green, change to list item 2 little circle go red. 
Also for some reason it doesnt recognize my radiobuttonlist1 in RadioButtonList1.Items

This is my html code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="listitemcss" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem >
        <p style="color:transparent;"> s2</p>
    </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">
        <p style="color:transparent;">2</p>
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And this my c#

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: green;");
    }
    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have and IDE in front of me, but if you want them to toggle with one being red and the other green, try this:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected)
        {
            RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: green;");
            RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");
        }
        if (RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Selected)
        {
            RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: green;");
            RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");

        }


}
```

Comment: it says RadioButtonList1 doesnt exist in current context

Comment: @Rasec219 And you didn't get that error on your original code?

Answer (score 1):

set autopostback property  to true

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="listitemcss" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem >
```

Comment: set `AutoPostBack` True